# Ember 2 Routable Components

Tags: ember.js

What is the preferred way of passing initial attributes to a routable component in Ember 2.2 Canary?

The way which is described in the RFC (https://github.com/ef4/rfcs/blob/routeable-components/active/0000-routeable-components.md#specifying-component-attributes) seems not to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: There is an addon to enable routable components in Ember 2.7 and later: https://github.com/mdehoog/ember-routable-components-shim

---

Currently only a small part of the routable components RFC is implemented in Ember Canary. The `attributes` hook has not yet been implemented. The only thing that gets passed to the routable component is the model returned from the `model` hook.

Here is an example implementation:

1. Create your routable component (instead of a controller). It must be an `isGlimmerComponent`:

   ```
   // components/post.js
   import Ember from 'ember';

   export default Ember.Component.extend({
     isGlimmerComponent: true,
     componentProperty: 'componentValue'
   });
   ```
2. Create your routable component's template:

   ```
   {{!-- templates/components/post.hbs --}}
   Model property: {{model.modelProperty}}<br/>
   Component property: {{componentProperty}}
   ```
3. Create a route that renders your routable component:

   ```
   // routes/post.js
   import Ember from 'ember';

   export default Ember.Route.extend({
     renderTemplate: function () {
       this.render({component: this.routeName}); //or you can explicitly name your component here
     },
     model: function () {
       return {
         modelProperty: 'modelValue'
       };
     }
   });
   ```
4. Add the route to router.js as normal:

   ```
   // router.js
   Router.map(function() {
     this.route('post', { path: '/post' });
   });
   ```
5. Visiting /post should now render your routable component.

Comment: Just to be clear. If you do `//or you can explicitly name your component here` name your routable component, it won't use the matching route's name correct? Like it won't use the routable component you created `components/post.js`.